# Decode GZIP response on Node.JS Man In the Middle Proxy

Tags: node.js, zlib

I'm working on a MITM proxy on Node using typescript. I'm trying to decode responses that are encoded using gzip. I don't want to just remove `accept-encoding` header as I saw in some answers here on SO. I want to use `zlib` to decode the response body, but for some reason when I try to load a page that uses gzip (like github.com for example) the page doesn't load (images, colors, texts, etc.). My decompress is not working and I don't know why. The code that I'm using to decompress the response body is the following:

NOTE: `serverResponse` is the response from the server that I (as the proxy) am connecting to (github.com for example) and `proxyResponse` is the response from me (the proxy) to the client that started the request

```js
  protected async receiveResponse(serverResponse: http.IncomingMessage, proxyResponse: http.ServerResponse) {

    const contentEncoding = serverResponse.headers["content-encoding"]
    let responseContent: http.IncomingMessage | zlib.Gunzip = serverResponse

    if (contentEncoding && contentEncoding.toLowerCase().includes("gzip")) {
      responseContent = zlib.createGunzip()
      serverResponse.pipe(responseContent)
      delete serverResponse.headers["content-encoding"]
    }

    let responseBody: Buffer

    try {
      responseBody = await this.collectMessageBody(responseContent)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return
    }
    
    proxyResponse.writeHead(serverResponse.statusCode!, serverResponse.headers)
    proxyResponse.write(responseBody)
    proxyResponse.end()
  }

  private collectMessageBody(stream: http.IncomingMessage | zlib.Gunzip): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      let bodyBuffers: Buffer[] = []

      stream.on('data', chunk => bodyBuffers.push(chunk))
      stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(bodyBuffers)))
      stream.on('error', error => reject(error))
    })
  }
```

It follows the same strategy that most answers here on the SO, but I don't know why mine is not working.

OBS: This is an open-source project, so the entire file can be found here: https://github.com/olmps/web-sniffer/blob/master/src/server.ts

I've simplified the logic removing unnecessary stuff to post here.

As an example, when loading github.com that uses `gzip` to compress its content, I get the following result when the proxy is on:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the assets such as stylesheets are not being loaded.

Comment: Yes! And I have no idea why. When I delete the header `accept-encoding` before sending the request to Github, it works fine, because obviously Github is not compressing the response. But when I don't delete this header and try to decompress the response locally, this is the result. I think that it's something beyond my knowledge or it's something REALLY stupid that I am not seeing.

Comment: From a quick read of the code, when you send an accept-encoding with gzip, then why are you encoding it again using zlib.creategunzip()? Either pass the response as it is or decode it before re-encoding it? When you don't send the accept-encoding header, then you get a raw response which you are possible encoding correctly.

Comment: @suv what do you mean with "encoding it again using zlib.creategunzip()" ? I'm piping a `Gunzip` to decode the response from Github server, not to encode it

Comment: Ah. That's a misleading function name. I just read the docs and you are correct. creategunzip decodes the gzip stream. Did you try console printing the response and see what's happening there? I can think of one another reason why this seems to be happening and a console.log should make it very clear.

Comment: @suv Actually the decoded responses bodies are HTML and JS contents from Github. As sdgluck said above, stylesheets are not loading for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to handle the `content-length` header as well.

If the `content-encoding` is `gzip` you can try to change the value of `content-length` header with the length of uncompressed body, not only to uncompress the body.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right into the point. Adjusting the `content-length` did the trick! SO is saying that I need to wait 6 hours before giving you the bounty, so I'll come back later to do it. Thanks for your solution, I'm actually surprised that NONE of the related answer here on SO mentioned this detail.

Comment: Happy you solved your problem. NP for the bounty... I can wait ;)